# Extending Border of an Element to Full Width of Container (No Display Block)

Tags: html, border, css

I am generating a PDF form from scratch using ColdFusion. CF can generate a PDF from HTML. So, I'm attempting to create a form that looks something like this... With under line under the entire space between label 1 (which actually ends after the colon) and the edge of the container (in this case, the body tag). Is there any way that I can do this using the CSS Border attribute, or is it possible to use the Background attribute with a custom background repeating (this is another way I've seen this done)?

```
|header     pg|
|    title    |
|             |
|lbl1:_val1___|
```

Simply not sure the best way to approach this, and I imagine there must be an easy way...

Front-End Guys? :)

EDIT: JSFiddle illustrating Issue Here... http://jsfiddle.net/JESw5/

Thanks,

Taylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using an inline-block element because you have tagged your question with it. All inline-block elements can be sized to fit their container with the following:

```
width: 100%;
```

That's it!

Add a border to the bottom and you're good to go:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwGdZ/1)

Comment: Hello, and thank you. I thought that that was the case, but I can't seem to get it functioning for some reason... I will attempt to readdress my HTML for the issue. I would upvote, but I have not enough rep... :(

Comment: Ah but wait! I've discovered a distinction between your example and my issue... Let me create a JSFiddle for you that illustrates my problem...

Comment: Well in that case, why not just [**apply the border to the div?**](http://jsfiddle.net/JESw5/1/)

Comment: The border cannot be shown below the label for the input. The desired outcome is like a line you would fill out on a pen and paper form, and thus needs to go to the end of the page, but only begin after the label. (I've already figured margins)

Comment: As far as I know, unless you want to use jQuery/JS, the only way to make this happen is to [**define a width on the label as well**](http://jsfiddle.net/JESw5/2/). The width of the span and the label should add to 100%.

Comment: OK, thanks very much David. I appreciate your help. I'll find some way to format it... :)